# Client template not working with custom helper action methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using the MVC Telerik controls and ASP.NET MVC 3 with the razor view engine.  I have my own helper methods for routing, for example:

```
public static object CategoryEdit(this UrlHelper urlHelper, int categoryId)
{
   return new { controller = "Category", action = "Edit", id = categoryId };
}
```

I have an AJAX grid and I have my own column template with a link in it going to the edit action method in the category controller, but I don't know how to display it correctly.  Currently I have this but it is not working:

```
column.Bound(x => x.Id)
   .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"" + Url.RouteUrl(Url.CategoryEdit(Int32.Parse("<#= Id #>"))) + "\">Edit</a>")
   .Title("Action")
   .Width(50);
```

When the grid loads it gives the following exception:

**Input string was not in a correct format.**

So I am assuming that `Int32.Parse("<#= Id #>")` is incorrect.

Comment: could you also explain what is that is not working

Comment: Yes, "<#= Id #>" is not a valid number. The code specified in the ClientTemplate is just a string which will later be interpreted as a template. It will not run your server side code on the client-side.

Comment: @Atanas: Have you got a solution for me then?

Comment: The solution was already given but its author seems to have deleted his response. The answer is to embed the <#= Id #> in the route value of the action link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static object CategoryEdit(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string categoryId)
{
   return new { controller = "Category", action = "Edit", id = categoryId };
}

column.Bound(x => x.Id)
   .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"" + Url.RouteUrl(Url.CategoryEdit("<#= Id #>")) + "\">Edit</a>")
   .Title("Action")
   .Width(50);
```